# Open Select2 dropdown with JS click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've tried simulating click with .click() function on every element within the container including the container itself. The dropdown won't open. Clicking with mouse works as it should.

```
<div class="select2-container select2-allowclear editor s-LookupEditor valid" id="s2id_AbCd_Q_CustomerEditDialog22_CstId">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   
    <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-2">Peter Smith</span>
    <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   
    <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
        <b role="presentation"></b>
    </span>
</a>
<label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen">Customer</label>
<input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" id="s2id_autogen2">
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code (jquery) and make a working snippet of the problem. It can be done by editing the question and clicking the `<>` button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a Select2 instance programmatically, invoke the `open` method on it:

```js
$('select').select2(); // initialise

$('select').select2('open'); //open
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Please select</option>
  <option>Foo</option>
  <option>Bar</option>
</select>
```